# How to add not null unique value to existing Django Model with default attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.11

I need to add slug field to django model, and i thing it's better when it not null. So i'm trying to add slug to model

```
slug = models.SlugField(
    'URL',
    unique=True,
    default=id_generator,
)
```

my id_generator:

```
import string
import random
def id_generator():
    size=16
    chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
```

The problem is when i migrate changes.
Method id_generator is calling one time and uses the same value for all model objects. So i have dupliicate entrie in unique field. How can i generate unique values? Django 1.11.5

P.S. I understand, that i can set null=True and customize model's save method to add slug when saving.

Comment: Side note and certainly an edge case: There's nothing in your id_generator that would guarantee uniqueness even if it was called for each instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add non-null and unique field with already populated model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749300/add-non-null-and-unique-field-with-already-populated-model)

Answer (score 1):

MOST IMPORTANT: You have not good generator for unique slug, may be best way use uuid for example

```
import uuid

slug = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

by [add-unique-fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields)

1. Added null=True, without default With data migration
2. Alter model with current filed description, with migrate.

example first step migration, replace YOUMODEL:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import string
import random
from django.db import migrations, models


def id_generator():
    size=16
    chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

def update_slug(pp, schema_editor):
    for instance in YOUMODEL.objects.all():
        #           ^^^^^^^
        instance.slug = id_generator()
        instance.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='YOUMODEL',
            #           ^^^^^^^
            name='slug',
            field=models.SlugField(null=True, verbose_name='URL'),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(code=update_slug)

    ]
```

Comment: i used my id_generator just for example. The question is why does this method called only one time, because i remember i set method in default value and it generated value for every model instance in older django versions

Comment: don sure that it was worked any time, by django docs [add-unique-fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields), maybe you are confusing something?